# Prompt buttons on tableviewcell

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am currently working on a Settings page use a tableview.  I want to create a tableviewcell such that when people click on it a number of buttons will prompt and users can choose from it.  An example of what I intended to do is the "Tell a Friend" button in Whatsapp's Settings (http://oi60.tinypic.com/sbotmr.jpg).

Is there anyway I can achieve it?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html). When user clicks on "Tell a Friend" cell , `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method gets called. On click of it , you can show UIActionSheet with options that you want to show.

Here is a link to [UIActionSheet tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uiactionsheet-and-uiactionsheetdelegate--mobile-11590) to get started

Let me know if it works for your requirements.